# trouble compiling std::tuple with clang

Tags: c++, templates, clang, stdtuple

I have trouble compiling templates with clang.. Any help appreciated.

Although the author of the library claims he compiled below code with gcc on linux, when I try to compile using clang, it complains about compiling templates below:

// this gives the error of "expected expression"

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3> static ostream& operator << (
    ostream& out, const std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>& t) {
  out << t.get<0>() << " " << t.get<1>() << " " << t.get<2>();
  return out;
}
```

this gives the error:

```
no member named 'get' in 'std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char>, int, int>'
```

Code:

```
void save_by_conns(vector<real_t> &container, const string &nam)
{
    LOOP(const WC_CONN_PAIR &p, connections)
    {
        VDI begin = container.begin() + p.second.get<2>();
        VDI end = container.begin() + p.second.get<3>();
        if (begin != end)
        {
            save_range(make_pair(begin, end), p.second.get<1>() + "_" + nam);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`get` for tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) for some reason is a free function, not a member function. So it should be `::std::get<2>(p.second)` and so on.

Comment: @VTT The reason is that the correct syntax for calling a member version in a dependent context is `t.template get<0>()`, and that's just annoying.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Though this is not the reason to not supply member version. They could've implemented both member and non member versions just fine like with `swap`.

Comment: @VTT why using (p.second)? The template parameter <2> already gives the second element. Am I wrong? But your suggestion compiles, too.

Comment: @eral isn't p a `pair` here? and `tuple` doesn't have `second` or `first`, it does not have anything but ctor, d-tor and `swap`. :P

Comment: @swift it is defined as typedef pair<string, std::tuple<string, string, int, int> > WC_CONN_PAIR;

Comment: @eral I assume that `p.second` is tuple itself, also index `<2>`  is zero-based so it gives third element.

Comment: I am asking usage in the first code part; ie.:  out << t.get<0>() << " " << t.get<1>() << " " << t.get<2>();   --- why not just std::get<index>(t) here instead of std::get<index>(t.index)

Comment: @VTT yes. Clear now. Thank you. Your answer solved my problem. But dont know how to check it as a valid answer from the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to retrieve `tuple` elements a non-member [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) function should be used:

```
out << ::std::get<0>(t) << " " << ::std::get<1>(t) << " " << ::std::get<2>(t);
```